# What Language and platform do you suggest

Tags: architecture, cloud, software-design, platform

I'm going to develop a web-based product and it has following descriptions:

1- It may grow to a big website and thousands of users!

2- It is gonna have an API to serve users so users can call the API in their own applications!

3- Security is so important!

4- 90% of jobs are done in the back-end but some designing and settings are done in the front-end!

5- Some parts are AI-based services!

6- Back-end is performed on tens of clouds so we need to manage clouds!

7- Speed is critical

8- It needs to communicate with some other API and softwares

Right now to prepare a demo I used PHP for website and C# as API for server side like AI, database, cloud management, app management. But for final product I'm confused what platform, language and so on use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many languages are enabled for the Cloud, including the ones you mentioned, I'd suggest you start with where your team is strongest. As Pierre noted in his answer, there's a learning curve to developing for the Cloud and throwing in a new language will slow things down, and you have listed speed as critical. Prioritize architecture: Good architecture has more weight than choice of tools.

Approach the project from a Micro-Service Architecture (MSA) perspective. Since you predict growth, you don't want to end up with a monolith and complicate scaling, reliability, speed to market etc. Try to slice up the solution into independent, deployable modules. This will also give you the chance to optimize your tooling and learn as you go.

Use the right database for the right job, it's becoming common practice to have multiple data-layer technologies in one project.

You mention

> Back-end is performed on tens of clouds so we need to manage clouds

Not certain of the meaning here but if you'll be going multi-cloud, consider using **Containers** and more open-ended orchestration engines like **Kubernetes**. Minimize **serverless** components, because that might mean redesigning for each Cloud Services vendor.

All the best.

Comment: I agree with all you say Pete, except I would waver from the Micro-services approach. It's an architecture I'm really excited with, but it's really tough to instanciate properly.

Comment: Agree, it's not easy nor straightforward with MSA's and fair caution is warranted: usually a trade-off in development but gains in operations excellence.

Answer (score 0):

For such a project, the first step is to build your cloud architecture from the components of your platform (for example AWS / Azure / GCP)

Language will come much later, according to the goals and constraints of your components.

Beware: deploying a "classic" application (i.e. not initially designed for the cloud) on the cloud may be VERY complex.